# tell gdb to disassemble "unknown" code

Tags: assembly, gdb, disassembly

is it possible to configure gdb in order to debug assembly code when there are no debug symbols or no sources available ?
I mean showing assembly instruction by assembly instruction when performing a step by step debug (next /step commands) (not desassembling all the function. just the next instruction that will be executed)

Regards,
 Ayman

Comment: I'm sure this is possible. Xcode does it by default and it uses gdb. Not sure how to configure plain ol' gdb to do it though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disassemble the main function of a stripped application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475790/how-to-disassemble-the-main-function-of-a-stripped-application)

Comment: GDB's TUI mode has `layout reg` which is pretty decent, but it won't let you scroll backwards when you don't have symbols, only forward.  (At least on x86 where variable-length instructions mean you can't unambiguously decode backwards.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set disassemble-next-line auto
```

Is what I find most useful. You can also set it to "on" to disassemble even if source is available.

See [the "Source and Machine Code" section in the documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Machine-Code.html).

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Use `display/ni $pc` to disassemble the next `n` instructions.

Also, download the [GDB manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/).