# Stripped binary shows "_cxa_finalize" instead of "libc_start_main"

Tags: c, gdb, disassembly, strip, objdump

Why stripped binary shows `_cxa_finalize` instead of `libc_start_main`?

I am trying to locate and disassemble `main()` in a very simple C program on Linux (Ubuntu). The binary is stripped. Below you can see disassembly (not stripped) vs disassembly (stripped) of the same instructions.

Question: what is `_cxa_finalize` in the stripped version? Why is `libc_start_main` is replaced by `_cxa_finalize`?

Not stripped:

```
106d:   48 8d 3d c1 00 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0xc1]        # 1135 <main>

1074:   ff 15 66 2f 00 00       call   QWORD PTR [rip+0x2f66]        # 3fe0 <__libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5>
```

Stripped:

```
106d:   48 8d 3d c1 00 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0xc1]        # 1135 <__cxa_finalize@plt+0xf5>

1074:   ff 15 66 2f 00 00       call   QWORD PTR [rip+0x2f66]        # 3fe0 <__cxa_finalize@plt+0x2fa0>
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not `__cxa_finalize`. It's `__cxa_finalize@plt+0xf5` and `__cxa_finalize@plt+0x2fa0` (notice the significant offsets). The disassembler has no information about the symbol `main` or `__libc_start_main` because you removed the symbol table, but for technical reasons it is still aware of the symbols assocated with PLT thunks (because they're needed for binding at dynamic linking time, and the disassembler probably falls back to using that information when it lacks s symbol table). In general, the disassembler works backward from an address until it finds an address named by a symbol, and assumes (wrongly, here) that the address being disassembled is part of that function.

Comment: Why this example of a stripped binary still has _libc_start_main??https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475790/how-to-disassemble-the-main-function-of-a-stripped-application

0x0000000000400464:  callq  0x400428 <__libc_start_main@plt>

Comment: @Harry: It's not `__libc_start_main`. It's `__libc_start_main@plt`, the PLT thunk which will provide the definition, and it's visible for exactly the same reason as `__cxa_finalize@plt`: there's a dynamic relocation for the GOT slot corresponding to that PLT thunk, without which dynamic linking would not be possible. If you static link and strip you will see that it's not there.