# "SO" file conversion to readable format

Tags: c, linux

Is there any way to convert ".so" file into source code or some in readable format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [tell gdb to disassemble "unknown" code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790781/tell-gdb-to-disassemble-unknown-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source code is probably hard, since the .so doesn't "know" which language it was written in.

But you can browse around in the assembly code by doing something like this:

```sh
$ objdump --disassemble my_secret.so | less
```

Comment: it's called objdump, not obj-dump. (Stupid SO won't allow the edit because it's under 6 chars, duh.)